# Finding the Correct Function that fits the Scenario

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, special-functions

i have been trying to find a function that fits the following scenario:
$$
f'(c) = 1^0
$$
$$
f''(c) = 2^1
$$
$$
f^{(3)}(c) = 3^2
$$
$$
f^{(4)}(c) = 4^3
$$
and so on, the purpose is to derive a way to find:
$$
B_{n,k}(1,2,3^2,4^3,\ldots) = B_{n,k}(f'(c),f''(c),f^{(3)}(c),f^{(4)}(c),\ldots)
$$
In terms of a function. I have derived a new way to find identities using discrete convolution of terms with this method. I am very interested in finding this function. The $c$ values must all be the same.

Comment: Why not just make the formal power series: $F(x) = \sum  \frac {(n+1)^n}{n!}\,x^n$ ?  That converges for |x|<1 (I think...I did it hastily so might have erred).  I don't think you'll find an elementary description of this function though...

Comment: Actually converges for $|x| < 1/e$ (use Stirling's approximation).

Comment: @RobertIsrael.  Well, yes.  I used Stirling to get my (wrong) answer...it helps if you use it correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for (for $c=0$) is $\dfrac{-W(-x)}{1 + W(-x)}$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: Where can i find out good information on the Lamber W function and what $x$ value does this work for?

Comment: The standard reference is Corless, R. M.; Gonnet, G. H.; Hare, D. E. G.; Jeffrey, D. J.; Knuth, D. E. (1996). "On the Lambert W function". Advances in Computational Mathematics 5: 329–359. https://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBF02124750 See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: The series converges for $|x|<1/e$, as has already been noted.

Answer (score 0):

I barely understand this, but that won't stop me from giving my understanding of the problem. I'll assume that you mean for the derivative of this theoretical function at the single value $c$ to be equal to the above.

In general you want.

$${{d^n f} \over {d t^n}}=n^{n-1}$$

Your solution will be a function, but without knowing initial conditions, the solution given here will be incomplete.

Take the Laplace transform of the equation. You'll get this...

$$p^n \cdot L={{n^{n-1}} \over p}$$

Solve for $L$...

$$L={{n^{n-1}} \over {p^{n+1}}}$$

Take the inverse Laplace transform. (look it up in a table if you don't do complex analysis)

$$f(t,n)=n^{n-1} \cdot {{t^n} \over {n!}}$$

Take the nth derivative of this function with respect to t, and you'll see that it satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Looks like you forgot a dollar sign! (Second to last line)

Comment: @Nkris thanks for the fix :)

Comment: @Nkris this does not work because the value of $n$ must be the same for all functions described in my question :(

Answer (score 0):

The power series given by Robert Israel converges when the absolute value of x is less than 1/e, as n! grows about as fast as the nth power of n/e (Stirling's Formula). This does give  a solution, if you replace x by x-c in the series.